# npm error "Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer webpack@"5.x.x" from @webpack-cli/serve@2.0.5"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, npm

[image: Error Image]

I using VS Code my project is not starting its giving npm error

"Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"5.x.x" from @webpack-cli/serve@2.0.5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try upgrading the `webpack` version.
2. Navigate to the ***root directory*** of your project in the Terminal, run the below commands to install ***webpack*** and ***webpack-cli/serve***:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
npm i -D webpack-cli @webpack-cli/serve
```

[image]

3. Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` in your project.

[image]

3. Run `npm start`
4. If it still gives error, run the below commands:

```
npm install --force
npm start
```